# How to add a listener in Hibernate for a specific database row changes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

[image]

I am developing a food ordering application, As shown in the image user1 will make payment and order  then call API `/waitForStatus/orderid` To get the confirmation of it, which should return only after Payment Provider confirms  back to us.

Payment Provider will update the table as Rejected or Confirmed using API `/confirmOrder/orderid`

My question is how to add a listener to a specific row and column.To know when provider updates back status

Here is my Entity Class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Order")
public class Order{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;
}
```

Here is my JPA Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    Order getOrderById(Long id);

}
```

Here is my Service class

```
@Service
public class OrderDomainService implements IOrderDomainService {
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;

    public OrderDomainService(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

   @Override
   public UserOrder getOrderById(Long orderId) {
         return orderRepository.getOrderById(Long id)
   }
   
   @Override
   public UserOrder waitForStatusCongfirmation(Long orderId) {
        
        //<-------------How to handle here
   }

}
```

Let me know how to listen for a change in specific row, Thank You.

Comment: Just google hibernate entity listeners

Comment: You can't listen for database changes. You have to use a task scheduler like [Quartz](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz) to periodically check for whichever Ids are on queue. There is no mechanism by which the database can ever notify the application for changes like that.

Comment: I think this must be done on the application level. If you want to do it synchronously, and by that I mean you are "blocking" user by having to wait for a reply from PaymentProvider then something like periodically checking the database can be one solution as a proposition from @coladict If you want to do it async, then maybe you can you just send a push notification to a user to let him/her know that the payment was successful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tool called Debezium that you can use to listen for any database changes: https://debezium.io/